# Overload make_heap?

Tags: c++, heap, overloading

I have a `std::vector<t_Mont> v`, `t_Mont` have {float val, int i and int j}

I want to do `make_heap(v.begin(), v.end())` and `pop_head(v.begin(), v.end())` but I get a lot of errors on console. I think this is because I'm passing a vector of type `t_mont`.

I want to `make_heap` on the value of the variable `val` of `v`.

What I have to do to compile me? I have to overload `make_heap` and `pop_head`? How I do it?

Thanks.

My code:

```
std::vector<t_Mont> v;
for (int i = 0; i < nCellsHeight; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nCellsWidth; j++) {
        t_Mont aux;
        aux.i = i;
        aux.j = j;
        aux.val = cellValues[i][j];
        v.push_back(aux);
    }
}

std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
while (v.begin() != v.end()) {
    std::cout << "Best of v = " << v[0].val << std::endl;
    std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.pop_back();
    std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make_heap` and related functions will, by default, compare values using `<`. You need to either provide an overload of that operator for your type:

```
bool operator<(t_Mont const & lhs, t_Mont const & rhs) {
    return lhs.val < rhs.val;
}
```

or provide a custom comparator when you call the functions:

```
auto comp = [](t_Mont const & lhs, t_Mont const & rhs){return lhs.val < rhs.val;};
std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
```

If you're stuck with an ancient pre-lambda compiler, define a function type in full:

```
struct Comp {
    bool operator()(t_Mont const & lhs, t_Mont const & rhs){return lhs.val < rhs.val;}
};

std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), Comp());
```

Answer (score 1):

`t_Mont` has to be comparable with `operator<` for this to work, or you have to use the other form of `std::make_heap` and pass a comparison functor alongside the iterators (if, for some reason, you don't want `t_Mont` to be generally sortable).

That is to say, you have to define

```
bool operator<(t_Mont const &lhs, t_Mont &rhs) {
  // return true if lhs is less than rhs, false otherwise.
}
```

so that you get a total order (i.e., `a < b` means `!(b < a)`, `a < b` and `b < c` mean `a < c`, and `!(a < a)`), or

```
struct t_Mont_compare {
  bool operator()(t_Mont const &lhs, t_Mont &rhs) const{
    // return true if lhs is less than rhs, false otherwise.
  }
}
```

with the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a function object for making comparisons between two t_Monts. The declaration of make_heap looks like this :

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare> 
void make_heap (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp );
```

Or just create a function like this :

```
bool comp_tmonts(const t_Mont& a, const t_Mont& b)
{
   /* Insert your comparison criteria for less than here.
      Return a boolean value corresponding to whether a is less than b */
}
```

Then pass this to your make_heap function as the third argument :

```
make_heap(v1.begin(), v1.end(), comp_tmonts);
```